# working php web application with SOAP

Tags: php, apache, soap, wsdl

What is the basic requirement configurations in apache (httpd.conf) or in php (php.ini) to support SOAP web application?

Apparently i successfully created a simple server-client soap application in my first machine, however when i transfer it to my second machine my application won't work.

I was wondering maybe the other machine won't support soap but checking both machine using phpinfo() i can view that each of them has soap support.

Eventually, I discovered upon viewing the wsdl file in the browser, the first machine can load the wsdl file like xml, meaning the browser can read my wsld file. On the other hand, in second machine the wsld was not loaded but "DOWNLOADED" :( I think this is where the problem is..

Is there any idea how to fixed wsdl will be load/read in the browser but not being downloaded? what could be the setting of my apache/php? is there a module need to install?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Did you tested your Web Service with a client? If yes which is the error message when you try your client in the new server?

Comment: Now it works.. the problem is that xml is not supported in the latter. :)